# openning windows hosts file in writing modes fails

Tags: c, windows, hosts

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

void main()
{
    const char * hosts_filename = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\drivers\\etc\\hosts";
    FILE * hosts= fopen(hosts_filename, "a");//also tried r+ and w modes
    if(!hosts)
    {
        perror("failed");//failed: Permission denied
        system("PAUSE");
        exit(1);
    }
    fprintf(hosts, "\ntest\n");
}
```

but it opens successfully in `r` mode.

If there is a restriction how [this dude](http://wikihacks.hpage.in/a-virus-profram-to-block-websites_29548522.html) opens the file for writing?

Comment: Try `perror("failed")` to see what the error message is - I suspect it's due to a lack of necessary permissions.

Comment: That website hurt my eyes.

Comment: @ScottyBauer yes, search result

Comment: @DrewMcGowen Permission Denied! What should I do?

Comment: @DrewMcGowen is probably 100% right. to give you some code that will work `printf("The error is - %s\n", strerror(errno));` make sure you include `#include <errno.h>`

Comment: @csstd run it as administrator...

Comment: @ScottyBauer Don't you like the beautifully formatted code displayed in the single perfect font face? Oh c'mon... :P

Comment: @H2CO3 I specifically like the little trail of w/e those are that followed my cursor.

Comment: use Administrative privileges command prompt

Comment: @ScottyBauer My user account is admin and also I run the program as admin but the same problem

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Can you explain more, please?

Comment: command prompt(in start menu) right click menu : Operate with administrative

Comment: @BLUEPIXY again the same error!

Comment: I can do what I've tried on windows7.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc947813%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I don't know I do the same thing under win7, did it print "test" in your file?

Comment: yes, "test" add last line.

Comment: ok, thanks very much, I think I should test on another system.